# How to split a table in 4 groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a table with two columns. The `Seq` column goes from 1 to 100.

```
Part_No             Seq
A23                  1
B88                  2
C34                  3
A43                  4
B48                  5
E11                  6
A87                  7
E64                  8
...TILL Seq 100
```

I now want to split this table like below:

```
Part_No_a             Part No_b            Part_No_c            Part_No_d
A23                     B88                  C34                   A43
B48                     E11                  A87                   E64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation with the modulo function:

```
select max(case when seq % 4 = 1 then part_no end) as part_no_a,
       max(case when seq % 4 = 2 then part_no end) as part_no_b,
       max(case when seq % 4 = 3 then part_no end) as part_no_c,
       max(case when seq % 4 = 0 then part_no end) as part_no_d
from databasetable t
group by ((seq - 1) / 4);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works like a charm. I am little curious what exactly does the Group By clause do?

Comment: Hi, you can read more regarding the GROUP BY here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp